# How to Get Checked Value of Check Box from a List View with gridview in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf

I have `ListView` with `GridView` used inside as shown below using WPF,now how can I get the selected Rows on Check Box Click. Please help me.

```
<ListView Name="lvWTMProductSelectionSku"  Style="{StaticResource ListViewStyle}" >
            <ListView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.Resources>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" >
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <CheckBox Visibility="Visible" IsChecked="{Binding IsSkuChecked}" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: The mentioning of CheckBox_Click makes me think you are using WPF just like windows Forms. Please don't, you are missing out on a lot of cool stuff that makes WPF so much better than Windows Forms. Look up MVVM and follow a tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for Valuable data,then how can i  achieve this can u help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- first define an `ObservableCollection` that will contains all the
  `ListViewItems`, Why `ObservableCollection` ? because that type of
  collections implements the `ICollectionChanged` Interface that allow
  you to track any changes in the collection and update the UI
  accordingly, your codebehind/ViewModel needs to implement the  `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface
- then define a `SelectedItem` Property and bind it to the `ListViewSelectedItem`, that property will contains the current
  selected item in your list,
- finally in the `checked` handler use the `SelectedItem` prop to do your whatever you want to do.

and the codebehind:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window,INotifyPropertyChanged
{      
    private ObservableCollection<Item> _ditemSource  ;
    public ObservableCollection<Item> DitemSource
    {
        get
        {
            return _ditemSource;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_ditemSource == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _ditemSource = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private Item _itemSelected  ;
    public Item ItemSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return _itemSelected;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_itemSelected == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _itemSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DitemSource = new ObservableCollection<Item>()
        {


                   new Item()
                   {
                       Name = "name1 ",
                       IsSkuChecked = false
                   },
                   new Item()
                   {
                       Name = "name2 ",
                       IsSkuChecked = true
                   }


        };
        ItemSelected = DitemSource.First();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(ItemSelected.Name);
    }
} 
public class Item
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSkuChecked { get; set; }      
}
```

That is one way to do it, you could of course directly get the `ListViewItem` by getting the parent* of the sender (which is a `CheckBox`) in the `checked` event handler, but that not an elegant way to do it.

Comment: thanks Sam,Here i can get a individual value ,how to get selected Row of Checkbox Checked

Comment: here in the solution above you need first to select the row before checking its CheckBox in order to get the row value, to bypass that you could use the CheckBox.DataContext .....for example in the checked handler above to use the Name Property you could get it like this :
var Name=(((sender as CheckBox).DataContext)as Item).Name;